# Verifying Deployment: FAILED using MUP for my meteor app

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, meteor, ionic-framework, mup

I have a problem deploying my app on my VPS.

Know that i tried to do it many time on different versions of UBUNTU:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)
- Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)
- Ubuntu 17.10 (64 bit)

Commands:

```
mup init
```

Then i filled and edited my mup.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
 servers: {
  one: {
      host: 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
      username: 'root',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
  }
 },
 meteor: {
  name: 'Ti3',
  path: '../myapp',
  servers: {
   one: {}
  },
  buildOptions: {
   serverOnly: true
  },
  env: {
   ROOT_URL: 'https://m.example.com',
   MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
  },
  docker:{
   image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
  },
  deployCheckWaitTime: 96,
  enableUploadProgressBar: false
 },
 mongo: {
  oplog: true,
  port: 27017,
  version: '3.4.1',
  servers: {
   one: {}
  }
 }
};
```

Then:

```
mup setup
```

Result is good:

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Docker
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Environment
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Environment
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Setup Environment: SUCCESS
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Copying mongodb.conf
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Copying mongodb.conf: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Start Mongo
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Start Mongo: SUCCESS

Next, you should run:
    mup deploy
```

Finally:

```
mup deploy --settings=settings.json
```

Result:

```
Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Prepare Bundle
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Prepare Bundle: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Configuring App
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Pushing the Startup Script
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Sending Environment Variables
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Start Meteor
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Start Meteor: SUCCESS
[XX.XX.XX.XX] - Verifying Deployment

[XX.XX.XX.XX] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

              ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
              Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                        throw(ex);
                                                        ^

        Error: Cannot find module './driver/base'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs/nod
e_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver.js:9:14)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                        throw(ex);
                                                        ^

        Error: Cannot find module './driver/base'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs/nod
e_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver.js:9:14)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                        throw(ex);
                                                        ^

        Error: Cannot find module './driver/base'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs/nod
e_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver.js:9:14)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                        throw(ex);
                                                        ^

        Error: Cannot find module './driver/base'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs/nod
e_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver.js:9:14)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        => Starting meteor app on port:80
        /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                        throw(ex);
                                                        ^

        Error: Cannot find module './driver/base'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs/nod
e_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver.js:9:14)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

              ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
              Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        Container has no IP Address, likely from it restarting.
        => Container status:
        restarted: 8 times {"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"00bb7547050558848ad7653c9abc34a93c7da49a1dc1b89112d7ee92e7e39f01","
HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Ports":{},"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/0
0bb75470505","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":
"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","MacAddress":"","Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMCo
nfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"499449ebea418f87e1471b837748344d48771428cfec20d0e6f597a8cffc6b61","E
ndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":
0,"MacAddress":"","DriverOpts":null}}} {"Status":"restarting","Running":true,"Paused":false,"Restarting":true,"OOMKilled
":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":0,"ExitCode":1,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2018-03-03T23:33:52.871342871Z","FinishedAt":"2018-03-
03T23:33:55.0535249Z"}
        => Logs:

        To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=200'


              ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Iam trying to figure out the problem from many days now, without any success.

I am developing under Windows:

- Node V8.9.0
- NPM V5.5.1

My app working well locally without any issue.

Need help to solve this problem please, you can suggest another solution if you have.

What i have tried ?

- I deleted the folder node_module and reinstalled them: `meteor npm install`

Same result !

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This explains about the correct socker images to be used. https://hub.docker.com/r/abernix/meteord, use respective meteord docker as per meteor and node version.

You should try this

```
docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.9.1-base'
    },
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it's helpful for the op and other people if you can explain why it's going to fix the problem.

Comment: This explains https://hub.docker.com/r/abernix/meteord/, use respective meteord docker as per meteor and node version.

Comment: Well that's getting better - if you edit your response it will improve it even more